# Return Unique items in a Go slice

Tags: performance, go

I'm trying to return unique items in a Go slice. I've landed on the following, but it seems rather sub-optimal. I'm new to golang (first project in it) and wondering if there's a better way to approach this?

```
// 
// Returns unique items in a slice
//
func Unique(strSlice []string) []string {
    keys := make(map[string]bool)
    list := []string{} 
    for _, entry := range strSlice {
        if _, value := keys[entry]; !value {
            keys[entry] = true
            list = append(list, entry)
        }
    }    
    return list
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not idiomatic writing style in Go, because the `value` variable is misleading:

> ```
> if _, value := keys[entry]; !value {
> ```

The first returned value is the value in the map, the second value indicates success or failure of the lookup.
So rename it to `ok` or `found`.

If the slice is very large,
then `list = append(list, entry)` may lead to repeated allocations.
In that case, you can optimize by preallocating `list` to the maximum possible capacity (`len(strSlice)`), and assign elements by index rather than using `append`.
But if you have no reason for this optimization then don't do it,
that would be premature optimization,
the current solution is fine.

Comment: Example here - https://onelinerhub.com/golang/how-to-get-unique-values-from-slice

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating you final slice during the loop, you could do two loops: one for creating the `map` and another to turn it into a slice:

```
//
// Returns unique items in a slice
//
func Unique(slice []string) []string {
    // create a map with all the values as key
    uniqMap := make(map[string]struct{})
    for _, v := range slice {
        uniqMap[v] = struct{}{}
    }

    // turn the map keys into a slice
    uniqSlice := make([]string, 0, len(uniqMap))
    for v := range uniqMap {
        uniqSlice = append(uniqSlice, v)
    }
    return uniqSlice
}
```

If your are not interested into the value of the map, it is customary to store the empty `struct{}`.

NB: this implementation will not keep any ordering of the input slice